# Suitable Alternative to div

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a plugin on me Wordpress/Woocommerce website which allows me to separate Brands from Categories - Woocommerce Perfect Brands.

I have added descriptions to my categories which works great however having difficulty with the brands description. My description is intended to display a snippet and give the user the option to view more via code

```
<div><input id=”post-1″ class=”read-more-state” type=”checkbox” />
    <div class=”read-more-wrap”>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <p>Main snippet.</p>
        <div class=”read-more-target”>
            <p>Additional Info.</p>
            <p>Additional Info 2.</p>
            <p>Additional Info 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <label class=”read-more-trigger” for=”post-1″></label>
</div>
```

My problem is the `div` and `label` elements are stripped and I end up with:

```
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<p>Main snippet.</p>
<p>Additional Info.</p>
<p>Additional Info 2.</p>
<p>Additional Info 3</p>
```

Which then does not provide the functionallity that I want.

I seen a post in the plugins support which states that the only supported elements are `<p><span><a><ul><ol><li><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><pre><strong><em><blockquote><del><ins><img><code><hr>`

I cannot see any suitable tags here to replace either the `div` or the `label`

Can anyone see or know of a work around to this?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have an access to stylesheet then HTML tags are actually non-important - you can display even a `span` tag same way as a div

For example

```
.read-more-wrap span {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would that then still allow me to use the `<label>` tag?

Comment: yes obviously as long as you take care of proper usage of `label for=` attribute and styling etc.

Comment: I tried replacing the div with span... this did not work either. it replaced the code with `<p>&nbsp;</p>`

Comment: Are the classes also stripped? If no then you can try using `p` tags instead of the divs and nest the other `p` tags inside - it won't be a valid html but it should work. It is hard to help without being able to play with your set up. Alternatively you can also try displaying such information dynamically via javascript

Comment: I don't think the classes are stripped. My main reason for doing this is to boost seo, I would be weary about usinh <p> tags incase that Had a negative seo impact